# Why my IIS 7 rewrite rule doesn't work?

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, iis-7

I have migrated a Wordpress Mu blog under Linux to WP 3 under IIS 7 so I need to redirect http://mydomain.com/blog/blahblah/ to http://mydomain.com/blahblah/

I added to wordpress web.config

```
        <rule name="rewrite /blog/">
            <match url="^/blog/([_0-9a-z-]+)/" />
            <conditions>                
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}/" />
        </rule>
```

so that web.config now contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
                <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url="*" />
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
        <rule name="rewrite /blog/">
            <match url="^/blog/([_0-9a-z-]+)/" />
            <conditions>                
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Wordpress continues to work but /blog/ is not redirected. Why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Better move this rule above Wildcard rule

2) You had leading slash `^/blog/...` -- you do not need it: `^blog/...`

3) Because no conditions were used I have also removed `<conditions></conditions>`

```
<rule name="rewrite /blog/">
    <match url="^blog/([_0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)/$"/>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}/"/>
</rule>
```

The above is **Rewrite** rule -- you see the same url in browser but behind it executes differently.

If you want **Redirect** then use the below:

```
<rule name="rewrite /blog/">
    <match url="^blog/([_0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)/$"/>
    <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: I copied and paste to web.config but redirects still doesn't occur: error 404

Comment: Ah ok thanks I don't really know the difference but now it works :)

Comment: `^` means "Start of subject (or line in multiline mode)" while `$` means "End of subject (or line in multiline mode)". Based on your example: with `$` it will match `blog/blahblah/` while without it will also match `blog/blahblah/blah-blah/even-more/blah/`. It really depends on your requirements/urls. Having `$` makes rule more precise. Based on my own experience (those sites where I was involved) I prefer to have it there.